New Angular @if template syntax is not working in my webapp
I am looking for your help.
The new Angular @if template syntax is not working in my Angular web app and to be more specific it seems that it is not recognized as a possible syntax. An example:

Does anybody know what to do? Thank you in advance.
I already updated Angular to version 18 and created a new test app. I got the same result.

you might need to install the angular language service extension

It looks like you are using an old version of WebStorm, which doesn't have support for control flow yet. Please update to at least v2023.3.2, or better v2024.1
See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2023/12/webstorm-2023-3-2/#notable_fixes
